# MAX 10-SAT Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, dynamic-programming

The MAX k-SAT problem is:

> “Given a set of clauses C1,…,Ck, each of length k, over a set of
>   variables x1,…,xn, find a truth assignment that satisfies as many of
>   the clauses as possible.”

I'm trying for find a randomized 0.999-approximation algorithm for the MAX 10-SAT problem. Help :(

Comment: is there any 99.9% approximation algorithm out there?

Comment: Note that every clause has exactly 10 variables. Choose a random assignment. Then, use linearity of expectation and remember you are dealing with 0-1 random variables. The same analysis works for other values of $k$ too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try choosing a random assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at chapter 5 of this book (available for free):

[The Design of Approximation Algorithms by David P. Williamson and David B. Shmoys](http://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf)

The book discusses several randomized algorithms with different performance guarantees for **MAX-SAT** and **MAX CUT** (for details of the algorithms, you should have a look at the references in the book).

Comment: The question asks about MAX 10-SAT, but your answer talks about MAX-CUT.  The connection is not clear.  You might want to edit your answer, or delete it if you misunderstood the question.

Comment: MAX-CUT and MAX-SAT have very similar approximation techniques so I think this answer is fine. I've edited to mention both.